# Converting empty strings to 0 using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array where each element looks something like this:

```
['3' '1' '35' '0' '0' '8.05' '2']
['3' '1' '' '0' '0' '8.4583' '0']
['1' '1' '54' '0' '0' '51.8625' '2']
```

I would like to replace all empty strings like the ones in the second row above, with some default value like 0. How can I do this with numpy?

The ultimate goal is to be able to run this: `S.astype(np.float)`, but I suspect the empty strings are causing problems in the conversion.

Comment: so these are numpy string arrays?

Comment: Yes. It's created using `np.array`

Comment: Can't the numpy arrays be used with list comprehensions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your array is t:

```
t[t=='']='0'
```

and then convert it.

**Explanation:**

`t==''` creates a boolean array with the same shape as `t` that has a True value where the corresponding `t` value is an empty space. This boolean array is then used to assign `'0'` only to the appropriate indices in the original `t`.

Comment: Cool, I didn't remember this construct, I was just about to post an answer with list comprehensions, but this is quite shorter!

Comment: @user1778770 use list comprehension only if you have a list. as long as you have a numpy array, you should take advantage of that.

Comment: I think you could make your answer even better by adding a link to a page where the construct you've exposed is documented. That's for those beginners who will wonder what's going on. I haven't found one

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach that uses map not that is does not produce the same data type as calling .astype():

```
def FloatOrZero(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except:
        return 0.0


print map(FloatOrZero, ['3', '1', '', '0', '0', '8.4583', '0'])
```

Outputs:

```
[3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.4583, 0.0]
```

It's possible that this approach will give you more flexibility to cleanup data but it could also be harder to reason about if you are wanting to work with a numpy.array.

Comment: are map, reduce faster than @askewchan's answer?

Answer (score 5):

Just do this first:

```
s = np.array(['1', '0', ''])
s[s==''] = '0'

s.astype(float)
#array([ 1.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: is this faster than map?

Comment: I was curious so I wrote a toy example using cProfile and they are not exactly the same. I suspect the overall work is roughly the same but calling map creates a new array of float values while calling astype(float) keeps the original np.array and just lets you see each value as a float. I now think this answer is better and just as readable so I updated my answer so people don't blindly copy bad information.