# Unidentified variable type in ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

I have this column

```
In  [] : parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP'].unique()
Out [] : 
array(['3.69', '4', '3.73', '3.24', '3.56', '3.3', '3.31', '3.74', '3.37',
       '3.19', '3.43', '3.5', '3.64', '3.46', '3.79', '3.14', '3.81',
       '3.21', '3.96', '3.7', '3.6', '3.55', '3.25', '3.07', '3.51',
       '3.67', '2.98', '3', '3.18', '3.53', '3.48', '2.93', '2.82',
       '3.39', '3.36', '1.62', '3.12', '3.27', '3.82', '3.89', '3.47',
       '3.68', '3.95', '3.86', '3.54', '3.63', '3.88', '2.8', '3.9',
       '3.4', '', '3.23', '3.78', '3.45', '3.41', '3.85', '3.52', '3.35', #Notice there's '' in this row
       '3.32', '3.66', '3.38', '3.71', '3.75'], dtype=object)

# I don't know what is it, I thought it's null so I checked it out like this

In  [] : parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP'].isnull().sum()
Out [] : 0 

In  [] : parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8[parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP']=='']['IP'].isnull()
Out [] : False

# Resulting if I do this, it returns error
In  [] : parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP'].astype('float')
Out [] : ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I don't know what it is and apparently it's not null and it's not whitespace too because when I look for it like `==' '` it returns no row. Since I have no idea what that is I don't know how to treat this error. Could someone help? I need to change that column into float and that unidentified `''` is blocking my way

Comment: There's an empty string `''` (which is different from the single-space string `' '` that you are checking for) in the column, which can't be converted to a `float`. You'll get the same error with `float('')`.

Comment: Okay, after looking for other cases they apparently use `.str.extract('(\d)').astype('float')` but it cuts the double digits behind the `.` which I need to capture as it is, ex. `3.41`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting empty strings to 0 using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936732/converting-empty-strings-to-0-using-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for omit the ''. Try this

```
condition = parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP']== ''
array = parsed_data_prodiTI_smt8['IP']
np.where(condition,array,array.astyp('float')
```